# PHP. Parse object ARRAY json

Tags: php, json

I have been searching lot of time but I didn't find anything that solves my problem. I tried pieces of code but they don't work for me. I'm using PHP 5.6.32

The problem is that I need to read a JSON and take some of the name:values and store these values in another JSON.

The JSON structure is like this:

```
[ {
  "fecha" : "1999-01-01",
  "indicativo" : "2661"
}, {
  "fecha" : "1999-01-02",
  "indicativo" : "2661"
}, {
  "fecha" : "1999-01-02",
  "indicativo" : "2661"
}, {
  "fecha" : "1999-01-02",
  "indicativo" : "2661"
} ]
```

As I understood, this is an array("[]") of objects("{}").
I try to use:

```
json_decode($response,true);
```

but it doensn't work. The $response is the JSON file(string).

EDIT:
I try to read the object with a foreach loop but I don't know how to get the name values of each object.

```
foreach ((array) $items as $item) {

}
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work? what is the result

Comment: "doensn't work." why bother posting, if your not going to explain the issue?

Comment: What doesn't work about this, see http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d5c220c4521f1df8f2280f569544e3e5d824f17f

Comment: Doing `$result = json_decode($response,true);` works for me... but I know what to do with the result... what are YOU trying to do with the result?

Comment: I just added more details

Comment: [`foreach`](http://php.net/foreach) ($items as **$name =>** $item) { … }

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I get an empty page :(

Comment: @mario I get this: 
Notice: Undefined variable: items
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: How do you set `$items`? And why do you think you need to cast it with `(array)`?

Comment: json_decode($response,true); 
and in the foreach $response["name"]
maybe you ment to  (stdClass) casting.
recommend you to debug usin xdebug or printing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what you're doing wrong, but this works:

```
<?php

$response = '[ {
  "fecha" : "1999-01-01",
  "indicativo" : "2661"
}, {
  "fecha" : "1999-01-02",
  "indicativo" : "2661"
}, {
  "fecha" : "1999-01-02",
  "indicativo" : "2661"
}, {
  "fecha" : "1999-01-02",
  "indicativo" : "2661"
} ]
';

$items = json_decode($response, true);
foreach ($items as $item) {
    echo "Fecha: {$item['fecha']} Indicativo: {$item['indicativo']}<br>\n";
}
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/qjaYc6)

Comment: I get this: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach().
If I do echo $response I get the JSON as string.

Comment: I've added an online demo showing that it works with no errors.

Comment: I just found the problem. The response has some accents (á, é, í, ó, ú) and they don't appear correctly. I delete these characters and it works perfectly.
I get the response from a website(url), in the browser all the characters appear correctly but when I get the response in my php code these characers are not encoded correctly.

Comment: That sounds like a problem with the website, they're not properly encoding their JSON.

Comment: No, in the web site it looks fine the problem is when I receive the JSON with file_get_contents(...)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Websites are HTML, not JSON. It sounds like you should be calling a proper API that encodes the response properly.

Comment: Exactly. I know websites are html. I’m calling an API. In the browser it looks fine but when I get the JSON with the php code there is some problem with the encoding.

Comment: Can you provide the API URL?

Comment: The API it's a spanish weather website, this is the API URL https://opendata.aemet.es/centrodedescargas/inicio
If you don't understand spanish just add some accents to the response.
Try with this:
    $response = '[ {
  "fecha" : "1999-01-01",
  "ciudad" : "León"
}, {
  "fecha" : "1999-01-02",
  "ciudad" : "León"
}, {
  "fecha" : "1999-01-02",
  "ciudad" : "León"
}, {
  "fecha" : "1999-01-02",
  "ciudad" : "León"
} ]
';

Comment: That's an HTML web page, with SSL certificate problems. I don't get JSON from that URL.